# How to fetch corresponding Name,when its delete button is pressed

Tags: java, android, string

John        Delete

Jane        Delete

ABC         Delete

XYZ         Delete

Trying to write a Android code to delete the corresponding name whose delete button is pressed.But not getting how to fetch the corresponding name when its delete button is pressed and I need to use **only String or stringBuffer methods** to accomplish this task.

Can anyone help me in accomplishing this task.

Below is the Mock up:

[image: Mock Up]

Comment: Can you please show your layout image?

Answer (score 0):

This Function Will Do Your Work.

```
 private void deleteIt(Button button,TextView textView)
    {
      button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Or You Can Use View.GONE
      textView.setText(""); //Setting A Null Text In The TextView.
    }
```

For Example:-

```
 xyzButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              deleteIt(xyzButton,xyzTextView);//xyzTextView = Your Text View To Delete
            }
          });
```

Comment: No,when I click on delete button JOHN should get deleted. Similarly when I click on delete of XYZ,XYz should be deleted.....in the above example delete is a button and not a string

Comment: What Do You Mean Deleting? Is That Removing The Text From TextView Or Removing The TextView Itself.@sainathpawar

Comment: removing text from TextView.

Comment: Please Take A Look I Have Edited My Answer @sainathpawar

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for above post.

```
public static void deleteText(TextView textView,Button button){

String text=textView.getText().toString();
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(text);

     StringBuffer deletedString = stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.length());
     textView.setText(deletedString);
     button.setVisibility(button.INVISIBLE);


 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.ABCDeleteButtonID: deleteText(ABCTextview,ABCDeleteButton);
    break;

    case R.id.JhondeleteButtonID:deleteText(JhonTextView,JhondeleteButton);
    break;

    case R.id.JaneDeleteButtonID:deleteText(JaneTextView,JaneDeleteButton);
    break;



}
}
```